# El significado de “si+ imperfecto subj + pretérito imperfecto” “Si me ofrecieran el puesto, lo aceptaba”

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, condicional

Si me ofrecieran el puesto, lo aceptaba

Me gustaría saber en qué situación se usa esta expresión y ¿como se dice eso en inglés?

Answer (score 1):

Although the more correct form is:

> Si me ofrecieran el puesto, lo aceptaría.

la forma:

> Si me ofrecieran el puesto, lo aceptaba.

can also be used in colloquial Spanish.

> En la lengua coloquial es frecuente hoy el empleo en la oración apódosis del pretérito imperfecto o copretérito de indicativo: *Si me tocara/tocase la lotería, me **compraba** un coche.* ([see 1.1.2.a](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=uqFr1XT7vD6KF3oDZL))

Answer (score 0):

Esa sería una expresión gramaticalmente incorrecta.
Imagino que la situación corresponde a la frase:

> Si me ofrecieran el puesto lo aceptaría.

Equivalente a decir en inglés:

> If they offered me the position, I would accept it.